# Audit Trigger for sys.triggers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm having the following problem.

I sometimes have people disabling triggers on my system.

How do I develop a trigger that fires an audit to a separate database table?

I've had a look at this [link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2085/sql-server-ddl-triggers-to-track-all-database-changes/)

The above link is very useful, but it only relates to alter or drop procedure or trigger.

Is there an `Event Type` for disabling triggers?

How will I go about setting up an audit for this?

Comment: Why do people you cannot trust have enough *permissions* to disable triggers on your database?

Comment: As per the [`CREATE SERVER AUDIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-server-audit-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) documentation, you can only have the results into a file, into windows logs (application log or security log), or to a URL (not sure what the last one does, I didn't find any reference to it later in the document.  Having said that, I did see that at least on my SQL Server 2016, the sys.triggers table does contain an `is_disabled` column, so perhaps that should be enough to get you what you need.

Comment: Personally I think someone in my organization is trying to sabotage me Damien.
They have the same permissions I do, so now, I need to be able to prove it.

Comment: No offence, but if this is "sometimes it seems like the trigger hasn't fired", more often than not, it's "the trigger is not correctly written for multi-row DML statements" rather than sabotage.

Comment: Understood and I agree Damien, but I know that my triggers were not badly written. It definitely fires every time it should.

Comment: Well, if we look back we can see that you are, in fact, one of those persons disabling triggers. So perhaps the problem is the original idea and design that lead you to this path?

Comment: Smor, I do not disagree with disabling triggers in the past and I did not implement anywhere in my triggers to disable the particular trigger in question that was disabled. So looking at my profile does give you that impression, but I will not post a question if I have not thought of that. Thanks for your contribution though.

Comment: Consider using an extended event session to capture all statements containing `DELETE TRIGGER` or `DISABLE TRIGGER`. This is potentially much simpler than a full-blown audit.

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert, can you maybe provide me with some examples?

Comment: Management Studio -> Management -> Extended Events -> Sessions -> right click -> New Session... From there, anyone who's ever worked with SQL Profiler should feel familiar, and even if you haven't it's fairly straightforward. `sql_statement_starting` is the event you're interested in.